# How to determine the fewest number of comparisons for Heapsort?

Tags: algorithms, heaps, comparison, heap-sort

I'm currently doing an exercise that asks to prove that Standard-Heapsort requires at fewest $\frac{1}{8} n \log(n) - O(n)$ comparisons, in its best case.

In its average case, Heapsort only requires $2n\log(n) - O(n)$ comparisons, although I don't know how to prove the best case scenario.

Can someone possibly hint me where to start with my calculation, I have no idea how to prove fewest number of comparisons, always been either worst case or most comparisons up until now.

Comment: [This](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/techreports/1990/293.pdf) paper might be of some interest, showing how to create a construction that results in $\sim \frac{1}{2} n \log n$ moves in the *best-case*. Where each move requires 2 comparisons, thus taking $\sim n \log n$ comparison. This doesn't follow your $\frac{1}{8} n \log n$, but maybe a similar construction can be found to fit this.

Comment: Yeah I've scoured through that, I literally reaad about 10 papers on Heapsort analysis and Algorithms, it doesn't seem like there's anywhere that has a proof for this

Comment: If you prove that it takes $\ge n \log n$ comparisons, then you've proven it takes $\ge \frac{1}{8} n \log n$ comparisons.  Yes, you'll have to deal with the asymptotics, but it sounds like that should be doable.  Rather than searching for some other existing solution that pattern-matches the expression you already have, perhaps you could try to understand the techniques in that paper and see if they are useful.

Comment: I think the exercise is asking for a proof on the fewest number of comparisons, not to prove an inequality, so for some best-case heap to prove that it can be done in as few as 1/8 n log(n) comparisons. I've read through that whole paper and the re-edit from 1992, plus watched around 20 videos on Heapsort and Heapify Optimization and I'm still stumped

Comment: Create best case scenarios for heapify and delete-min=>repair. What are those cases? These can only be the ones that require comparisons obviously. How many comparisons does a binary tree require to repair these cases? Depending on the tree level, what is the probability that the child is bigger then its parent, and how many comparisons are needed in average to repair this heap defect? It's not trivial but doable.

Comment: Even easier, how many comparisons are needed when you insert the values in asc order? and how many comparisons are required to repair then? This can only be the best case (min-heap). Heapify costs O(n), when you insert the value in order you dont need a repair  (except for one comparison each without traversing parents). So you need to calculate the limit of "delete-min" for a continously shrinking tree when the currently biggest value is at the root and deleteD-min again. At least that is what comes first to mind.

Comment: So I modelled a best case Heapsort array, in ascending order, obviously heapify() runs in linear time because the array is already sorted. Then you begin the process of deleting and reheaping, where most of the comparisons are gonna be made, but for an ordered array, for example array with size 7 [1,2,...,7], the amount of comparissons I've counted is minimum 10, which is not 1/8 * n log(n), it's better than n * log n but not even close to 1/8 * n log(n), thats 1.7 or if you ceiling, 2 comparrisons which is not even possible to achieve

Comment: Granted the question states "requires at least 1/8 * n log(n) comparisons" but, I assume you have to prove in some case that 1/8 * n log(n) comparisons is achievable, otherwise where would they have gotten this number from?